# Passing Several Data from Several Rows in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-forms

I'm so confused on how would i submit an array of data if i click several rows in angular? I am confused on how would i add row and submit data from that several rows. I've used (ngSubmit) for submitting data and i have (click)="onAddRow(rowIndex)" for adding rows. thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onCreate(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="card-block">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Project ID</th>
          <th>Material SKU</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Total Quantity</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>           
        <tr *ngFor="let addRow of row; let rowIndex = index">
          <td>
            <select type="text" class="col-md-10" id="project_id" name="project_id" ngModel required disabled>
              <option [value]="project.id">{{ project.id }}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select type="text" class="col-md-10" id="material_id" name="material_id" ngModel required>
              <option *ngFor="let material of materials" [value]="material.id">{{ material.sku }}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" id="unit" name="unit" ngModel required></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" id="quantity" name="quantity" ngModel required></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteRow(rowIndex)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onAddRow(rowIndex)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

> ts

```
row = [{}];

 onAddRow() {
    this.row.push({});
  }

  onDeleteRow(rowIndex) {
    this.row.splice(rowIndex, 1);
  }

onCreate(form: NgForm){

// HOW WOULD I PASS SEVERAL DATA IF I HAVE SEVERAL ROWS?

    const formData = {
      project_id: form.value.project_id,
      material_id: form.value.material_id,
      unit: form.value.unit,
      quantity: form.value.quantity
    }
```

> project_id

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params 
      .subscribe((params: Params) => { 
      this.id = +params['id']; 
      this.projectsService = this.injector.get(ProjectsService);
      this.projectsService.getProject(this.id)
      .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.project = data;
            console.log(data);

          },
          error => {
            alert("ERROR");
          })
      });  

      this.getAllMaterials();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go ahead and move to reactive forms, especially since you have an array, reactive forms have the exact thing for you that you need, i.e `FormArray` :)

import the necessary stuff (add `ReactiveFormsModule`) to your ngModule, and in your component import

```ts
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
```

build your form:

```ts
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    rows: this.fb.array([])
  })
  // called when adding new formgroups to your array
  this.initGroup()
}

initGroup() {
  let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  rows.push(this.fb.group({
    material_id: ['', Validators.required],
    unit: ['', Validators.required]
  }))
}

onDeleteRow(rowIndex) {
  let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
  rows.removeAt(rowIndex)
}
```

Template would look like this, where you declare the formgroup, formarray and then iterate the formgroups that are in your formarray, where each group has the index value:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <button (click)="initGroup()">Add row</button>
  <div formArrayName="rows">
    <div *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <select formControlName="material_id">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let material of materials">
          {{material.id}}
        </option>
      </select>
      <input formControlName="unit" />
      <button (click)="onDeleteRow(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

To get your array from the form, you can get the array with the following piece of code:

```ts
onSubmit() {
  this.formData = this.myForm.get('rows').value
  console.log(this.formData); // here is your array
}
```

This is the way I'd go :) Finally, here's a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bthrz2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: well you have the values in `myForm.value`, which can be seen in demo. So if you want to access it in component you can do it just by `this.myForm.value` :)

Comment: Hi @AJT_82. I needed project_id not to be inputted  in the input field BUT i need it to save to the form. How can i make it not visible to the form but it must be included when passing to the (ngSubmit)? I got project_id from the route params. Can you check my post above for the project_id.

Comment: You can just add it as a form control but not show it in the DOM :)

Comment: Here you can see that I added `someValue` but it is not shown in the view: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czf2nl?file=app/app.component.ts